# How do I display all the Methods or keyboard Shortcut to display them?

Tags: android, android-studio, methods

I'm using Android Studio now and I'm kinda like new to it. Just wondering how do I display all the Methods all the Methods apart from Ctrl+i for a particular method and Ctrl+F10..? I'm using mobile now so can't upload a pic but I'll do ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alt + insert on windows and command + N on Mac should do it. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html) on developer.android.com for more awesome shortcuts

Comment: haha no problem. you should know the beggining is the toughest. later its just like playing video games :) check out some video tutorials when you are free. thenewboston on youtube is a good one

Comment: I do this everyday mate,...and new to the Android Studio..haha I'd deffo have a look! Running a project now... wish me luck xx haha

Comment: godspeed to you mate :)